# Run Java SE code in Android

Tags: java, android, apk, sign

How can I run `SignApk.class` run in **Android**?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bi1ckssvrq20b58/SignApk.java

```
/** Write a .RSA file with a digital signature. */
    private static void writeSignatureBlock(
            Signature signature, X509Certificate publicKey, OutputStream out)
            throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        SignerInfo signerInfo = new SignerInfo(
                new X500Name(publicKey.getIssuerX500Principal().getName()),
                publicKey.getSerialNumber(),
                AlgorithmId.get("SHA1"),
                AlgorithmId.get("RSA"),
                signature.sign());

        PKCS7 pkcs7 = new PKCS7(
                new AlgorithmId[] { AlgorithmId.get("SHA1") },
                new ContentInfo(ContentInfo.DATA_OID, null),
                new X509Certificate[] { publicKey },
                new SignerInfo[] { signerInfo });

        pkcs7.encodeSignedData(out);
    }
```

I need to run this code in Android devices but it can't access to `sun.security`
and `sun.misc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to run this code you need to add library for that, So here I am posting a link to the library, please go through that and let me know for issues

**Link:-** http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadandroidsunjarsignsupport11jar.htm